# Relation between finite fields $F_{p^2}$ and $F_p(\omega)$.

Tags: finite-fields

Let $F_p$ be a finite field having $p$ elements(for some prime $p$), not having primitive 
$3$rd root of unit say $\omega.$ Then can i say that field  $F_p(\omega)$ and $F_{p^2}$ are isomorphic.

I tried as follows: As both of fields $F_{p^{2}}$ and $F_p(\omega)$ are of same dimension $2$ over the field $F_p$ and hence same number of elements. Now any two finite field with same number of elements are isomorphic.

Please suggest me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, it is correct. Note that $\omega$ is the root $x^2+x+1$, thus having order $2$.

Comment: Okh .... thanks .....